# AIR Android crash report on 4.4 Moto X

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, crash, adobe

My application that I've got on the Android market is crashing on a few devices, and working fine for others. it's target is supposed to be all android versions, AIR 3.2 with runtime embedded.

This is the report:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.nativeSurfaceCreated:()V
at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.nativeSurfaceCreated(Native Method)
at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(AIRWindowSurfaceView.java:672)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1902)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's going on? Thanks!

Comment: AIR 3.2 is now 2 years old (March 28, 2012). We are currently on 4.0 (with 13.0 expected next month, yay for new versioning schemes). You should consider updating to AIR 4.0 and seeing if the issue persists. A lot of app-crash errors on mobile are related to AIR itself, not to your code (especially on Android). Looking at your log, it would seem that AIR crashes while creating the environment your code will run in

Comment: Okay so I upgraded to Adobe CC, and the AIR version is now 3.8. Should that work?

Comment: You should upgrade further to 4.0. But I have no idea if it will work. I just know that what you have now is out of date. You'll need to test it on-device to find out if it will work or not.

Comment: Flash cc doesn't have 4.0, how do I get it?

Comment: If you're using Flex, easiest way would just be to grab the Flex installer and select AIR 4.0. Otherwise: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/overlay-air-sdk-flash-professional1.html

Comment: This is an Adobe bug, please vote on it here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3598923